# New to python but can't get this discord bot to run, I have no errors and i have it on the server what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

## bot.py

I am running it in pycharm.I press run and it goes and has no errors but I am not sure why it doesnt work on discord is it a setup error?

```
import discord
import random
import time
import asyncio

TOKEN = "*************************************************"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

if message.content.startswith("Hello"):
    await message.channel.send("Hi it is me KEVIN")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print("running rn sir")
```

Comment: To help out others who might have encountered a similar problem, please explain how you fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

If your code looks like it was shared here, it is due to a few small errors.

1. A few lines are not indented correctly.
2. You need [client.run](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.run) to initialize the bot

I corrected the code so it should work

```
import discord
import random
import time
import asyncio

TOKEN = "*************************************************"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("Hello"):
        await message.channel.send("Hi it is me KEVIN")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("running rn sir")

client.run(TOKEN, bot=True, reconnect=True)
```